# Capture Display Name from Azure AD B2C SUSI user flow in dotnet core Razor Page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure B2C with dotnet core 3.1 Razor Page web app using Microsoft.Identity.Web. I have it running and have been able to sign on using the [latest templates](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki). In my B2C1_susi User Flow I collect Display Name and Email. I would like to show Display Name in my _LoginPartial.cshtml instead of User.Identity.Name:

```
<li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="EditProfile">
          <span class="text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!/span>
     </a>
</li>
```

How do add additional fields to User.Identity and have them capture the Display Name and Email from the sign-up/sign-in user flow?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net Core 3.1 Razor page you can display all required user claims returned in the token using `@User.FindFirst("ClaimName").Value`.

For example `@User.FindFirst("emails").Value` can be used the display the email claim and for Display name you can also use `@User.GetDisplayName()`